# Why do I not have "Shared printer" within group policy preferences in Win 2008 R2 gpmc?

Tags: windows-server-2008, printer, group-policy

I have performed some research, and it appears that I can target both `XP` and `7` clients with `group policy preferences` to add a `shared printer`.

[This article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732092.aspx) describes the presence of a Shared Printer item on the `New` menu in the `group policy preferences` `Control Panel Settings` item `Printers`, but all I have listed are: `TCP/IP Printer` and `Local Printer`.

The server which I am using to create the `GPO` is `Windows 2008 R2`.

Why doesn't the `New` `Printer` option allow me to create a `Shared Printer`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you in the right configuration container?  It only shows up in the User Configuration, not the Computer Configuration (since the user account/profile is required to map to a shared printer).

[image: GPO pic]

Comment: Note [the answer here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverGP/thread/b11e3ad1-7941-48a3-90a5-a40dce0c8c09) describes a method of using a local printer, and assigning the port the UNC path to the desired printer.  This policy is available to the HKLM/Computer scope.

Comment: @mbrownnyc - as mentioned on that thread, this is where Loopback processing of a GPO comes into play.  If you want this to apply to a group of computers, you can use Loopback processing to make this work (say for a lab or a particular floor of computers)

Comment: Thanks again!  [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757470(v=WS.10).aspx) & [kb](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231287).  Instead of using this, I simply adjusted `item-level targetting` of `ip address range` on the `shared printer` `GPP`.